# InternalServerError while trying to load data from database

Tags: symfony, routes, fosrestbundle

Well i just started with FosrestBundle in symfony but i still have a lot of issues and was hoping someone can explain a few things to me.

this is my routing.yml

```
    app:
        resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
        type:     annotation
    route_name:
      pattern: /test
      defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Controller:AfsprakenController:postAfspraken, _format:json }
```

my config.yml

```
    imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: en

framework:
    serializer:
        enabled: true
    #esi:             ~
    #translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #     path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }

gregwar_captcha: ~
fos_rest:
    routing_loader:
            default_format: json
    view:
            formats:
                json: true
                rss: false # removing them will also work
                xml: false
```

And here is my controller:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use FOS\RestBundle\View\View;
use AppBundle\Response as AfspraakResponse;

class AfsprakenController extends FOSRestController
{

    public function postAfspraken(Request $request)
    {

        $data =  $this->getAfspraken();
        $view = $this->view($data, 200)
            ->setTemplate("MyBundle:Users:getUsers.html.twig")
            ->setTemplateVar('users')
        ;

        return $this->handleView($view);
    }

    public function redirectAction()
    {
        $view = $this->redirectView($this->generateUrl('getafspraken'), 301);

        return $this->handleView($view);
    }

    public function getAfspraken() {

        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:Uren');

        $result = $repository->findAll();
        return $result;

    }
}
```

When i run the localhost:8000/test i get a whole page of errors to be honnest but the first line says this:

```
{"error":{"code":500,"message":"Internal Server Error","exception":[{"message":"Unable to parse the controller name \"AppBundle:Controller:AfsprakenController:postAfspraken\".","class":"LogicException"
```

What am i doing wrong to render the view of all the information of my Uren?
And can you explain what i am doing wrong? I am very new to FosRestBundle and stack overflow so i am doing my best to get everything sorted

Comment: Please, put here your model code.

Comment: With model code you mean the code of the entity uren?

Comment: In FOSRestBundle you need to add "Action" to your function: "postAfsprakenAction". Look at http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/5-automatic-route-generation_single-restful-controller.html for more details.

Comment: I don't know FOSRestBundle but, according to standard symfony routing, change your controller name in routing.yml to `_controller: AppBundle:Afspraken:postAfspraken`. Also rename method `postAfspraken` to `postAfsprakenAction` in AfsprakenController class.

Comment: Done everything i still get a error called 

Controller \"AppBundle\\Controller\\AfsprakenController::postAfsprakenActionAction\" for URI \"\/test\" is not callable."